Default value of list when Source is null with java MapStruct
I have the following Mapper in MapStruct:
 @Mapping(source = "deptList", target = "deptList")
 TargetEntity toTarget(SourceEntity source);

I want to return '[]' when the source dept is null, then I tried like this:
 @Mapping(source = "deptList", target = "deptList", defaultValue="java(List.of())")
 TargetEntity toTarget(SourceEntity source);

but the compiler shows that could not convert java(List.of()) to List deptList, am I missing something? what should I do to return the [] by default when source entity is  null using mapstruct?

What exactly compiler complains about?

Try this way:
@Mapper
public interface EntityMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "deptList", target = "deptList")
    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_EMPTY)
    TargetEntity toTarget(SourceEntity source);
}

Or this:
@Mapper
public interface EntityMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "deptList", target = "deptList")
    TargetEntity toTarget(SourceEntity source);

    @AfterMapping
    default void handleNullDeptList(SourceEntity source, @MappingTarget TargetEntity target) {
        if (source.getDeptList() == null) {
            target.setDeptList(new ArrayList<>());
        }
    }
}


markdown is your friend!

You need to set
nullValueIterableMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT

in @Mapper. No need in defaultValue.

Have you tried using defaultExpression instead of defaultValue? The latter uses the strict value, while the first uses an expression language (see javadoc: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapping.html).
